# How can I use cookies to re-order the site, since in order to get a json from the website I need to be logged in?

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm already getting login cookies from the website. How can I use these cookies to make another requests to the site, since in order to get a json from the website I need to be logged in?
I'm doing this:

```
        string formParams = string.Format("user[email]={0}&user[password]={1}", "****@********.com", "********");

        string formUrl = "https://*************.com/users/sign_in"; 

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
```

Now i need to make a request to this link: https://********.com/parishioners.json?entity_id=13723

Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `re-order`?

Comment: I want to mean make another requests using the cookies of log in

Comment: Do any of these help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=C%23+webrequest+pass+auth+cookies

Comment: @mjwills Yes, is what i want. I already try a lot of things, but when i will do the second request after login request, i got ever 401 error.